# How to use a div tag as a starting point for searching an html document with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML document, and I want to parse out a table with a specific id, which is always within a div tag with a specific id.  Here is what I've tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
target_div = soup('div', {'id' : 'left'})
target_table = target_div.findNextSibling('table')
```

Clearly that's not working.  It seems that my second statement returns a ResultSet instead of moving me around the document (which I suppose makes sense, but I'm not sure how to get what I need otherwise!).  What is the correct methodology for doing this kind of parsing?

Comment: "A table with a specific id" - I assume it's a typo and there's no id on the table? It'd be trivial otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findNextSibling` looks for tables that are contained in the same parent as the original `target_div` element. You want to look for a table *contained in* the div. Use `.find()` for that:

```
target_div = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'left'})
target_table = target_div.find('table')
```

and for simple cases (such as the contained table) you can use the tagname as an attribute:

```
target_div = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'left'})
target_table = target_div.table
```

You were calling a tag, which is like using the [`.find_all()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all). `.find_all()` returns [all matching tags](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all), a list. You'd have to loop over the result set, but since you are looking for a *single* div (using its id) you are better off using [`.find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) which returns just *one* result.

If you do need to process more than one match, just treat the result of `.find_all()` as a list; loop over it:

```
for element in soup.find_all('div')
    contained_table = element.find('table')
```

or use indices:

```
second_match = soup.find_all('div')[1]
```

Comment: I`d also tried that and got "ResultSet has no attribute find"

Comment: @Jim: ah, corrected my answer; you want to use `find()` still. :-) `.find()` returns the *first* element. Calling or using `.find_all()` returns a sequence of matches (over which you can loop).

Comment: Ah, very nice!  Thank you for your help.

Comment: And note that `soup.find("foo")` is equivalent to `soup.foo` =) *cough*its not it's*cough*

Comment: @katrielalex: :-P Still trips me up from time to time. Corrected and augmented!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
target_table = soup.select('div#yourid > table#yourtableid')[0]
```